# Working out $\hat r\cdot \hat e_2$

Tags: vectors

I am working in a right-handed orthonormal coordinate system with the bases $\hat e_1,\hat e_2,\hat e_3$. I am trying to work out the dot product of the unit position vector with the $\hat e_2$ axis. I have acknowledged that the dot product of $\hat r\cdot \hat e_3$ is equal to $\cos\theta$ by inspection as in the picture below, as the angle $\theta$ is between the two vectors.

However, there is no direct angle between the $\hat e_2$ and the $\hat r$ vector. I have reasoned that the dot product of $\hat r\cdot \hat e_2$ will be the equivalent to the unit parametrisation of the y axis, being $\sin\phi\cos\theta$. I believe this to be the likely result as the dot product of $\hat r\cdot \hat e_3$ is equivalent to the unit parametrisation of the z axis.

[image]

**In short:**

- Is $\hat r\cdot \hat e_2=\sin\phi\cos\theta$?

Thanks

Comment: pretty sure it should be $\sin \theta$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates

Comment: @peek-a-boo Can you explain why?

Comment: refer to the answer given below. But to reiterate, even if you're not convinced why it should be sin, atleast you should be convinced it cannot be cos, because you already found the inner product of r and e3 has a cosine term

Comment: @peek-a-boo So via that reasoning would $\hat r \cdot \hat e_1=\sin\theta$ also?

Comment: @peek-a-boo or did you simply mean to replace the $\cos\theta$ in $\sin\phi\cos\theta$ to become $\sin\phi\sin\theta$?

Comment: Yes, sorry I should have been more explicit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Examine again the right triangle in your illustration. Its hypotenuse has length $r$ and as you’ve already found, the vertical leg has length $\lvert r\cos\theta\rvert$. By the Pythagorean theorem, if for no other reason, the length of the other leg, which lies in the $x$-$y$ plane, must have length $r\sin\theta$. That line segment is itself the hypotenuse of a right triangle with one leg along the $x$-axis. Can you take it from there?

N.B.: This is summarized in the formulas for converting from spherical to Cartesian coordinates that you can find [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinate_system#Cartesian_coordinates).

Comment: I cannot see the way forward

Comment: @Σbaryon You have a right triangle with hypotenuse $r\sin\theta$ and know the angle $\varphi$. What are the lengths of the opposite and adjacent legs to this angle? This is really basic trigonometry at this point.

Comment: So is the answer $\hat r \cdot \hat e_2=\sin\phi\sin\theta$?

Comment: @Σbaryon Just so!